# Make a new row for each group using summarize and across? dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, mutate, across

I have a database ag_prod4 that is structured as so:

```
country  item  element 1961 1962 ... 2021
usa      corn  Area    5    6    ... 8
usa      corn  Prod    8    4    ... 2
usa      corn  Yield   8    4    ... 2
usa      oil   Prod    8    4    ... 2
.
.
```

I want to make a new row with the element "efficiency" for each country-item group (ex: usa-corn) that is, for each year, Prod/Area.
*Note: Sometimes there are more/less than three elements for each country-item combination, or they are in a different order*

This is what I have so far:

```
ag_prod4 %>% group_by(country, item) %>%
  summarize(
    element = c(unique(element),"efficiency"),
    across(starts_with("1961"):starts_with("2021"), 
           ~ ifelse(element=="efficiency",VALUE,.))
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

This is almost there, but I need to put something in place of VALUE that, for 1961, will take usa corn production/usa corn area.

Thanks so much for the help! This is my first time posting, but I'm so stuck

Comment: For better, faster help please share a representative sample of your data. See here for tips: [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

Comment: I can't check this without some sample data, but I think something like `ag_prod4 |> pivot_longer('1961':'2021') |> pivot_wider(names_from = element, values_from = value) |> mutate(efficiency = Prod / Area)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       check.names = FALSE,
           country = c("usa", "usa", "usa", "usa"),
              item = c("corn", "corn", "corn", "oil"),
           element = c("Area", "Prod", "Yield", "Prod"),
           `1961` = c(5L, 8L, 8L, 8L),
           `1962` = c(6L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
           `2021` = c(8L, 2L, 2L, 2L)
) |>
  pivot_longer(`1961`:`2021`) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = element, values_from = value) |>
  mutate(efficiency = Prod / Area)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  country item  name   Area  Prod Yield efficiency
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
1 usa     corn  1961      5     8     8      1.6  
2 usa     corn  1962      6     4     4      0.667
3 usa     corn  2021      8     2     2      0.25 
4 usa     oil   1961     NA     8    NA     NA    
5 usa     oil   1962     NA     4    NA     NA    
6 usa     oil   2021     NA     2    NA     NA
```

Comment: for OP: keep your data in a tidy format, and it makes it a lot easier to transform! See [here](https://research-hub.auckland.ac.nz/guide-to-managing-research-data/organising-and-describing-data/tidy-data) for more info